# Split up array into rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table, row

I have a table, with values from `dat_eb_registrants` as rows (e.g. `$row[1]`) and values from a horizontal array, extracted from `dat_eb_field_values`, I'd like to split those up so I can order everything into the table how I want it.

How the data gets put into my table:

```
$count = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
$myArray[] ="<tr><td>" . $row[9] . "</td><td>"; echo $myArray[$count];
$count++;
echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

How all of the data get extracted from the database (yes, I know it's old):

```
SELECT dr.id, dr.first_name, dr.last_name, dr.email, dr.comment, dr.amount, dr.published, dr.transaction_id, dr.register_date, GROUP_CONCAT(df.field_value SEPARATOR '</td><td>') 
   FROM dat_eb_registrants dr 
   LEFT JOIN dat_eb_field_values df 
    ON dr.id=df.registrant_id
   WHERE `event_id` >= 20 AND `event_id` <= 25
   GROUP BY dr.id
   ORDER BY '".$sort."', '".$ascdsc."'
```

Now, I want to put some rows from the first table (e.g. `$row[1]`) and (.eg. `$row[2]`) vertically, in the middle of the array. How can I do this?

Because the array fills my table in one time, and using the `$rows`, you can simply tell which rows to display where...

This is what I want (code might not be correct):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>"'.$row_table_1[1]'"</td>";
echo "<td>"'.$row_table_1[2]'"</td>";
echo "<td>"'.$row_table_2[35]'"</td>";
echo "<td>"'.$row_table_2[45]'"</td>";
echo "<td>"'.$row_table_1[5]'"</td>";
echo "<td>"'.$row_table_2[6]'"</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

I used to do:

```
echo "<td>"; $result24 = mysql_query("SELECT field_id, field_value FROM dat_eb_field_values WHERE (field_id = 88) AND (registrant_id = $row[0])"); $r24 = mysql_fetch_row($result24); echo $r24[1]; echo "</td>";
echo "<td>"; $result25 = mysql_query("SELECT field_id, field_value FROM dat_eb_field_values WHERE (field_id = 57) AND (registrant_id = $row[0])"); $r25 = mysql_fetch_row($result25); echo $r25[1]; echo "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
```

I want to do:

```
echo "<td>" . $rowfromsecondtable[1] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $rowfromsecondtable[2] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
```

(using the code I gave above)

Preview of `dat_eb_registrants`:

```
    |   id   |   first_name   |   last_name   |   email               |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |    1   |      Mike      |     Doe       |   mikedoe@hotmail.com |
    |    2   |      John      |     Smith     |   j_smith@hotmail.com |
```

Preview of `dat_eb_field_values`:

```
field 1 = fav.sport
field 2 = fav. color
field 3 = fav. food

    |   registrant_id   |   field_id  |   field_value    |
----------------------------------------------------------
    |    1              |      1      |     tennis       |
    |    1              |      2      |     green        |
    |    1              |      3      |     spagetti     |
    |    2              |      1      |     hockey       |
    |    2              |      2      |     red          |
    |    2              |      3      |     fish         |
```

I need:

```
first_name  |   id   |   fav.sport   |   last_name   |   fav.food   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Mike        |    1   |      Tennis   |     Doe       |   spagetti   |
John        |    2   |      Hockey   |     Smith     |   fish       |
```

Comment: Struggling to understand this question.  Could you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: And once again :) The `mysql`-extension is oudated, not maintained and will be marked as deprecated with PHP5.5. Use `PDO_MYSQL`, or `MySQLi`. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Comment: I actually meant, could you provide more concrete example *of your data schema*.  It *sounds* as though this should all be possible in SQL, probably just from joining your tables and introducing an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause... but I see you already have both a join and an `ORDER BY` clause in your question, so I'm confused.

Comment: ok, now i can't make it any more clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something but why not just perform this task in SQL.  This is basically a *pivot*. MySQL does not have a pivot but you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select r.first_name,
  r.id,
  r.last_name,
  max(case when f.field_id =1 then f.field_value else null end) As FavSport,
  max(case when f.field_id =2 then f.field_value else null end) As FavColor,
  max(case when f.field_id =3 then f.field_value else null end) As FavFood
from dat_eb_registrants r
left join dat_eb_field_values f
  on r.id = f.registrant_id
group by r.first_name, r.id, r.last_name
order by r.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2b1c/2)

The result of the query is the output that you want:

```
| FIRST_NAME | ID | LAST_NAME | FAVSPORT | FAVCOLOR |  FAVFOOD |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|       Mike |  1 |       Doe |   tennis |    green | spagetti |
|       John |  2 |     Smith |   hockey |      red |     fish |
```

Or you can use multiple joins on the `dat_eb_field_values` table:

```
select r.first_name,
  r.id,
  r.last_name,
  fSport.field_value FavSport,
  fColor.field_value FavColor,
  fFood.field_value FavFood
from dat_eb_registrants r
left join dat_eb_field_values fSport
  on r.id = fSport.registrant_id
  and fSport.field_id = 1
left join dat_eb_field_values fColor
  on r.id = fColor.registrant_id
  and fColor.field_id = 2
left join dat_eb_field_values fFood
  on r.id = fFood.registrant_id
  and fFood.field_id = 3
order by r.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2b1c/3). It produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question but instead of using $row[9], $row[10] etc, you can just use the column names of your table as the row index.

$row['first_name']
$row['last_name']

and so on.  It'll make your code more readable.

You might also want to grab all your data at first and then generate your html code.  It'll look cleaner.

e.g

```
$result24 = mysql_query(sometihng here); 
$r24 = mysql_fetch_row($result24);

$result25 = mysql_query(sometihng else here); 
$r25 = mysql_fetch_row($result25);

//php code for table starts here 
echo '<table>';
```